# Losing focus when opening Material-UI Select programmatically

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, material-ui

I am trying to develop a hook which is a filtered Select, according to a TextField input. When the user type in the TextField, I like to show the list of available items to choose from. I have tried to use the open state property of the Select, but when I trigger it, the TextField loose focus in favor of the Select which is really impractical, when you are typing.

I am looking to a way to show the list without loosing the focus, any idea ?

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
    FormControl, InputLabel, MenuItem, TextField, Select
} from '@material-ui/core';

export default function AddressSearchLookup(props: any) {
    const [key, setKey] = React.useState('');
    const [openSelect, setOpenSelect] = React.useState(false);

    const [filteredAddresses, setFilteredAddresses] = React.useState([] as any);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (key.length > 0) {
            var addrs = props.Addresses;
            addrs = addrs.filter((a: any) => a.key.toLowerCase().startsWith(key.toLowerCase()));

            setFilteredAddresses(addrs);
        }
        else
            props.OnAddressChange('');
    }, [key]);

    const onSelectAddress = (e:any) => {
        if(key !== e.target.value)
            setKey(e.target.value);

        props.OnAddressChange(e.target.value);
    }

    const onKeyFieldChanged = (e: any) => {
        if (key !== e.target.value)
            setKey(e.target.value);

        setOpenSelect(true);
    }

    return (<span style={{ width: '100%', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <FormControl variant="outlined" style={{ width: '30%' }}>
            <TextField
                value={key}
                variant="outlined"
                label={"Key"}
                name="key-label-placeholder"
                onChange={onKeyFieldChanged}
                inputProps={{
                    name: 'keySearchAddress',
                    id: 'keySearchAddress'
                }}
            />
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl variant="outlined" style={{ width: '70%' }}>
            <InputLabel id="address-select-outlined-label" >Adresse</InputLabel>
            <Select
                labelId="address-select-outlined-label"
                id="address-select-select-outlined"
                name="address"
                open={openSelect}
                onClose={() => setOpenSelect(false)}
                onOpen={() => setOpenSelect(true)}
                value={props.Address}
                onChange={onSelectAddress}
                label="Addresse"
                displayEmpty
            >
                {
                    filteredAddresses.map((ctr: any) => {
                        if ('text' in ctr)
                            return (<MenuItem key={ctr.key} value={ctr.key}>{ctr.text}</MenuItem>);
                        else
                            return null;
                    })
                }
            </Select>
        </FormControl>
    </span>)
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you should be using the [Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#autocomplete) component. It is designed for these kind of use cases and handles the focus appropriately.

Comment: @RyanCogswell yes, I saw it, but it's still in the lab, and can change anytime...

Comment: It has been in the lab for quite some time now and is pretty stable. v5 (still in beta, but stable release coming in the next month or two) moves Autocomplete from the lab to the core.

Comment: Still open to any suggestions, thanks for your help.